# Redis Database Design Basics

Tags: database-design, redis

I have designed my first Redis database and would like some feedback, suggestions or tips.

**Overview:**

My redis database stores articles which can be later sorted by likes, date created, date updated, author etc...

Articles also contain "items" I would also need to determine which articles have alteast 1 item in them.

**Creation**

When a new article is created I write its ID to various keys

ZADD 'articles:created' Timestamp ArticleID

ZADD 'articles:updated' Timestamp ArticleID

ZADD 'articles:likes' 0 ArticleID

SADD 'user:USERID:articles' ArticleID

Whenever an article is updated

ZADD 'articles:updated' Timestamp ArticleID

Whenever an item is added to an article

ZADD 'articles:itemCount' ItemCount ArticleID

And if an item is removed, and no items remain, I simply delete its member

ZREM 'articles:itemCount' ArticleID

So when it comes to sorting I do the following:

1. I perform a ZUNIONSTORE with 'articles:likes' and 'articles:updated'
2. With the result I perform a ZINTERSTORE against the result and 'articles:itemCount'
3. With the result I simply perform a ZREVRANGEBYSCORE

This all works find and does what I want it to do, however I am new to Redis and open to suggestion and improvement.

Sincerely,

-- James

Answer (score 0):

I agree with your solution.

for improvement, think about the `Transaction`

**Creation**

> MULTI
>
> ZADD 'articles:created' Timestamp ArticleID
>
> ZADD 'articles:updated' Timestamp ArticleID
>
> ZADD 'articles:likes' 0 ArticleID
>
> SADD 'user:USERID:articles' ArticleID
>
> EXEC

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and thank you for suggesting the MULTI command, I have 1 further follow-up question. 

The more ways I would like to filter results, the more keys I need to create for that specific purpose, obviously each key simply contains an article ID and a score, currently we have about 30 different ways of filtering, coming from SQL this seems very odd as each ID is duplicated across 30 different keys.

So in short, is this simply how its done, and if so, does this make redis a bad choice for my requirements.

Sincerely,
-- James